# Ext deployed application: ext.js vs ext-all.js - what's a better option?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Looking at the [deploy process for an ExtJS 4 application](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/guide/getting_started) I performed the following steps (using SDK Tools 2.0.0-beta3):

```
sencha create jsb -a http://localhost:8080/myapp/ -p app.jsb3
sencha build -p app.jsb3 -d .
```

This created for me `all-classes.js` and `app-all.js`. The next step was to switch form `ext-all.js` to `ext.js`. Doing that my app stop working. Looking at the console, I noticed that Ext tried to load the required classes separately, from a `src` folder.

```
src/AbstractPlugin.js?_dc=1372193551701
```

So, I'm assuming that `ext.js` requires the `src` folder that have the unminified version of the components, and it will do one request for each component that my view require, correct?

In this case `ext-all.js` would be a better option, but it load all components, even the ones that I don't need (1MB size).

Is there some way to build an `ext.js` version only with the required components (maybe with SDK tools)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These 2 files serve different purposes.  `ext.js` contains the core functionality needed to run an application, while `ext-all.js` contains **all** of the framework code.  The first one will require your components to correctly use the `requires` and `uses` config properties to organize your code dependencies properly.  Then, when you run Sencha Command to build the app, all of your classes will be combined with the core from `ext.js`, and all your other dependencies from the ExtJS library that you included, and put into that `app-all.js` file.

If you are trying to use the Sencha SDK to build your app, I would **strongly** recommend upgrading to the latest version (Sencha Command version 3, available here: http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download) - they have fixed many, *many* bugs, and it works very well out of the box using the tutorial located here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/command.

Comment: Sencha cmd is the answer indeed. I just [had to adjust](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?246508-Setting-up-your-Architect-Touch-projects-to-be-used-with-Sencha-Cmd-v3&p=901360) my Architect's project. Thanks!