# How to include only the part of extjs library which is being used?

Tags: javascript, extjs, load, components, sencha-cmd

I want to include only required components from Extjs library.

I have seen couple of articles as follows,

http://blog.mdsohelrana.com/2012/10/21/how-to-compile-extjs-for-production-to-include-only-the-needed-ui-elements/#comment-461257

[Ext deployed application: ext.js vs ext-all.js - what's a better option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307383/ext-deployed-application-ext-js-vs-ext-all-js-whats-a-better-option)

Above articles says that after editing index.html file with required components and using following commands,

```
sencha create jsb -a index.html -p site.jsb3

sencha build -p site.jsb3 -d
```

will generate app-all.js file. But app-all.js file loading all components from extjs library..

Is there any alternate solution?

Answer (score 0):

The first article you mentioned is really old (2012). This command is no longer supported. I recommend to read the Sencha Cmd docs [link](http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.x/extjs/cmd_app.html) . You should also mentioned what version of Ext JS and Cmd you using.
I would say that you need use this command

```
sencha app build production
```

Then navigate to build/production. In ext folder, you will always have all ExtJS library.

Comment: Using Extjs 6.x version and sencha cmd 6.0.2

Comment: Ok and what is the problem then? When you make a production command you create a folder (build/production) where is your build output which contains only required Ext JS libraries.

Comment: index.html - in this file i have added ,
Ext.require([
       'Ext.grid.*'
]);

then created JSB and single JS file using sencha commands.
So now in  my application, I should be able get only grid component from ext library, right? But it is loading everything.